# recursively download tif files from website

Tags: python, tiff, scrape

What is the best approach to recursively discover and download tiff files from a website? For example, this url (https://geonb.snb.ca/downloads2/imagery/) contains several sub-directories (eg, 2014, 2015, etc..) and each of them have several tiff files that I would like to discover and download (see for examaple https://geonb.snb.ca/downloads2/imagery/2014/D19077/geotiffs/26220E74598N.tif).

Answer (score 0):

```
def loopdir(dirs):
     imgs=[]
      dirs=[]
  for dir in dirs:
    for records in dir:
          if record==img:
               imgs.append(record)
          else
             dirs.append(record)
  return (imgs,dirs)

dirs=['init']
images=[]
while dirs:
     imgs,dirs=loopdirs(d)
     images +=imgs
     dirs+=dirs
```

Comment: Thanks, Edo, but this does not solve the discovery of images on a website.